# How Can I Automatically Modify A State?

Tags: corda

I have a flow from Party A to Party B where I save a NEW state.

Shortly after that, Party B starts a new flow with some extra identifiable info to the state and sends it back to Party A as EDITED.

Does this have to be 2 separate flows? Or can Party B add the extra info to the state during the responder?

It would probably end up triggering multiple responders something like this:

```
Party A Initiate -> Party B
Party B Modify + Respond -> Party A
Party A Verify + Respond -> Party B
Party B Verify -> Party A
Party A finalises transaction
```

If this isn't possible, is it possible to trigger the EDITED flow as soon as the NEW is complete? e.g.

```
Party A Initiate NEW -> Party B
Party B Verify + Respond -> Party A
Party A finalises NEW transaction/state

//Automatically:
Party B Initiate EDIT -> Party A
Party A Verify + Respond -> Party B
Party B finalises EDIT transaction/state
```

Could you have a service that listens for NEW and starts the EDITED flow as soon as the NEW is complete?

Answer (score 0):

1- You can't modify a state in the responder, because the initiator already signed the state; meaning the initiator is testifying about the authenticity of certain data.
2- This should happen in 2 flows and you can automate that using `SchedulableState`:
- [Documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/event-scheduling.html)
- [Example CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/schedulablestate-heartbeat)
- [More](https://training.corda.net/corda-details/automation/) explanation and exercise/solution